# elasticsearch, how to delete multiple indexes with wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to delete all `*-meow` indices.

but wildcard expression are not allowed for `DELETE`

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed"},"status":400}
```

How do I delete them , there are many of them..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please refer `action.destructive_requires_name` in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html which controls the use of `wildcard` in delete operations.

PUT _cluster/settings

```
{
    "transient": {
        "action.destructive_requires_name": false // allow wildcards
    }
}
```